# Poincaré inequality in unbounded domain

Tags: inequality, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Help me please, how can I show that Poincaré inequality doesn't hold in an unbounded domain?

Thanks a lot!

If $\Omega$ is a bounded domain and $u \in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ the following inequality holds :
$\left \| u \right \|_{L^{2}(\Omega) }\leq c \left \| \nabla u \right \|_{L^{2}(\Omega) } $

where $c$ depends only on $\Omega$ and not on $u$.

Comment: can u write down the inequality , just for reference !

Comment: @Ananda I have added inequality, thanks!

Comment: Start with $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$ and consider a sequence of functions which are constant on $[-n, n]$ then decay smoothly and vanish outside of $[-n-1, n+1]$. Suppose by contradiction that the inequality holds and see what happens for $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Poincaré inequality is true if $\Omega$ is bounded in a direction or of finite measure in a direction.
- But not in general: if $\Omega=\mathbb R$, $\varphi$ smooth with compact support and such that $\varphi=1$ on $[0,1]$, $\varphi(x)=0$ if $x\geq 2$ (bump function), $\varphi_n(t)=\varphi\left(\frac tn\right)$, we have
  $$\lVert \varphi_n\rVert_{L^2}^2=\int_0^{+\infty}\varphi\left(\frac tn\right)^2dt=
  n\int_0^{+\infty}\varphi(s)^2ds\geq n$$
  and $$\lVert\varphi'_n\rVert^2_{L^2}=\frac 1{n^2}\int_0^{+\infty}\varphi'\left(\frac tn\right)^2dt=\frac 1n\int_0^{+\infty}\varphi'(s)^2ds$$
  so Poincaré inequality cannot be true (if it was, we would be able to find $c>0$ such that $\lVert \varphi_n\rVert^2_{L^2}\leq c^2\lVert \varphi'_n\rVert^2_{L^2}$ hence $n\leq c^2\frac 1n$ for each $n$, which obviously can't hold).
- For necessary and sufficient conditions, [I don't know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97147/open-sets-and-poincares-inequality).

Comment: Thanks a lot, very good explanation and example.

Comment: @Davide Giraudo what do you mean by bounded in a direction ?